# Whats the correct and efficient way to delete a versioned document in Filenet P8 4.5 or higher?

Tags: java, filenet-p8, filenet, filenet-content-engine

I want to delete documents for which a specific property has been set in the current version. If this property has been set all versions of that document need to be removed.
My current implementation which searches for `IsCurrentVersion = TRUE and foo = 'bar'` has the problem that only the current version gets removed and not the older ones. So I assume that I need to delete the complete VersionSeries ?
Till now I use

```
doc.delete();
doc.save(RefreshMode.NO_REFRESH);
```

for each document I find. How can I retrieve all documents from the series and have them deleted too ? And is it more efficient if I add this to a batch ?

Comment: if you want to have a more efficient delete(lots of files to edit or delete) checkout this: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_5.2.0/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.ce.doc/batch_procedures.htm?cp=SSNW2F_5.2.0%2F10-2-1-4-0

with the batch api you can bundle the save actions to save on roundtrips to the server.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should call the

```
delete()
```

method for the VersionSeries (http://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_5.2.0/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.java.doc/com/filenet/api/core/VersionSeries.html) instance,

```
VersionSeries vs = doc.getVersionSeries();
vs.delete();
vs.save(Refresh.NO_REFRESH);
```

Quote from docs

***Caution**: The delete and moveContent methods impact all document versions in the version series. That is, all document versions are deleted, and the content of all document versions are moved.*

Answer (score 1):

Method for deleting all the versions of a document from FileNet

```
public void deleteDocumentFromCE(String filenetDocGUID) throws Exception 
{
    System.out.println("In deleteDocumentFromCE() method");
    System.out.println("Input Parameter filenetDocGUID is : " + filenetDocGUID);

    Document document = null;
    UserContext uc = null;
    ObjectStore os = null;
    Subject subject = null;
    VersionSeries vs = null;

    try 
    {
        if (filenetDocGUID != null) 
        {
            getCESession(); //This method will get the CE session and set it in ceSessionData private class variable

            os = ceSessionData.getObjectStore();
            System.out.println("ObjectStore fetched from CESession static reference is : " + os.get_Name());

            subject = ceSessionData.getSubject();
            System.out.println("Subject fetched from CESession static reference.");

            uc = UserContext.get();
            uc.pushSubject(subject);

            if (os != null) 
            {
                document = Factory.Document.fetchInstance(os, filenetDocGUID, null);
                vs = document.get_VersionSeries();
                vs.delete();
                vs.save(RefreshMode.NO_REFRESH);
                System.out.println("All Document Versions deleted : " + filenetDocGUID);

            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Error :: Object Store is not available.");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Exception in deleteDocumentFromCE() Method : "+ e.getMessage());
        //pass the error to the calling method
        throw new Exception("System Error occurred while deleting the document in CE.. "+e.getMessage());
    }
    finally 
    {
        if (uc != null)
            uc.popSubject();
    }

    System.out.println("End of deleteDocumentFromCE() method");
}
```